# Pass a function with an event AND parameters, without an infinite loop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, react-hooks, dom-events

I use the Material UI library with React and I want to display a TextField.

```
const Input = memo(
({ type, name, required, placeholder }) => {
  console.log(type)
  if (type === 'number') {
    // Init input value
    if (typeof values[name] !== 'undefined') {
      setValues({ ...values, [name]: 0 })
    }

    let handleNumber = e => {
      console.log(e.target.value)
      setValues({ ...values, [name]: e.target.value })
    }

    return (
      <TextField
        required={required}
        type="number"
        id={name}
        label="Numéro du collier"
        name={name}
        margin="normal"
        variant="outlined"
        className="addAnimal-input"
        value={values[name]}
        // onFocus={setIsSidebarOpen(true)}
        onChange={handleNumber}
        // onBlur={validate(name)}
        // error={errors[name]}
        placeholder={placeholder}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

For now I want the onChange method to work but it causes an infinite loop and I don't know how to fix it.
I tried to call the method like that :

`e => handleNumber(e)`

Which didn't help.
Others things I tried I would not manage to pass the event, or the parameters.
The problem here is that after I call `setValues()` it re-renders the parent component infinitely but I don't see why :/

Comment: From where is the `setValue` is coming from? i couldn't see any `useState` in your code.
Also the `init input value` could you remove that and checked?

Answer (score 1):

Notice `const [values, setValues] = useState({})` is missing in your snippet.

The issue here is calling the state setter `setValues` inside the render function.
It's not a good practice, and you've just discovered why, it can cause infinite loops ;)

Here's the flow:

1. Assuming you start by hitting the key "a" (just for the sake of my example, this applies for any key that changed the input value).
2. `handleNumber` is called, it changes `values`, by setting the `{ [name]: "a" }`.
3. Setting a new state triggers a re-render.
4. The expression in your render function `typeof values[name] !== 'undefined'` is `true` since `typeof "a" === "string"`, so another re-render happens, this time with `{ [name]: 0 }`.
5. The expression `typeof values[name] !== 'undefined'` is still `true`, since `typeof 0 === "number"`. Then we get another re-render, and so on.